# Is there a way to make a service container file in laravel through command line?

Tags: laravel, command-line

I want to make a command line to make all modules i need in every single project in laravel..I have searched a lot but i can't get a direct answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is a "service container file"?

Comment: Service Container file is a file which i can write all functions i need and use it in multiple controllers through injection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a shortcut to generate all the needed files for routes/controllers/models/views, I would suggest this amazing package to use. It makes your life easier and it saves some time for the routine steps you have to do when you need a new module.

[Laravel-Modules](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules)

Comment: Thanks for your help I may be think to use this instead..Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @AhmedHassan Moreover, It's very easy to modify this package to any structure you want and add any further file since it's open source. So in your case, if it doesn't support creating service container, you can do it yourself.
 Please consider marking the answer as correct if you find it so.